# Unable to turn logging down on isc-dhcp-server on ubuntu xenial

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, journald

I edited /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf and set

```
log-facility local4;
```

I've also edited /etc/systemd/system.conf and set

```
LogLevel=notice
```

I've verified that the log level is set to notice with the command.

```
systemctl -pLogLevel show
```

None of that seems to be affecting the logging of isc-dhcp-server at all. It is still logging every DHCPACK and DHCPREQUEST and DHCPDISCOVER to

```
/var/log/syslog
```

I also restarted the isc-dhcp-server service after making these changes and ran the command to have systemd read its configuration again.

```
service isc-dhcp-server restart
systemctl daemon-reload
```

How can I turn down the logging on isc-dhcp-server on Ubuntu Xenial?

Comment: I'm assuming you restated the dhcp server process after making those changes? Just checking.

Comment: I did, but thank you for reminding me to include that in my description.